# Рекурсивная печать файлов проекта

Tags: c++

Как в c++ рекурсивно напечатать названия всех файлов в директории, переданной параметром программе? Например, для следующей структуры

```
--project
---src
----main.cpp
---include
----stdafx.h
---debug
----main
---Makefile
```

надо, чтобы вызов `debug/main .` печатал названия всех файлов проекта.

Comment: Укажите операционку: Linux / Windows. (**stdafx.h** вызывает панику, а **Makefile** - хорошее настроение)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Linux + Windows

Comment: std::filesystem ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe "Makefile - хорошее настроение" - с чего бы это?

Answer (score 0):

Только Linux (если понравится):

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic writedir.cpp
# include <errno.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <dirent.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <string.h>

void  showdir(char const * dirname,int depth){
  errno = 0 ;
  DIR * dir = opendir(dirname);
  if(errno) return;
  struct  dirent  * result;
  do{
    result  = readdir(dir);
    if(not result)  break;
    for(int i=depth;i>0;){--i;std::cout<<"-";}
    std::cout<<result->d_name<<"\n";
    if( (strcmp(result->d_name,".") not_eq 0) and
        (strcmp(result->d_name,"..") not_eq 0))
      showdir(result->d_name,depth+1);
  }while(true);
  closedir(dir);}

int main(){
  showdir(".",0);
  return  0;}
```

Comment: На MinGW тоже должно работать...

Answer (score 0):

Имея под боком `std::filesystem` из C++17 проблема по сути решается одним единственным циклом с [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator):

```
for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("project"))
    std::cout << p << '\n';
```

Для проверки см. [тут](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/149fa9f2d8a4a7ce).